# Javascript combine two arrays into new multi-dimensional array 3 dimensions deep

Tags: javascript

I am looking to combine array1 and array2 into a new array of objects with the output being like that of the results array.

My issue is combining the GIds and aggregating the CIds into that object.  I am trying to follow es6 array prototypes(map,filter,reduce) as well, but I am still new to it.  How do I get the GIds array to also contain the GId and an array of unique CIds.

Failed snippet from the current code GId: 1 should have one object with two CIds[1,2]:

```
   "GIds": [
      {
        "GId": 1,
        "CIds": [
          1
        ]
      },
      {
        "GId": 1,
        "CIds": [
          2
        ]
      }
    ]


const expectedResult =  [
    {
      "BId": 1,
      "Name": "Test1",
      "States": [{SId: 2, GIds: [{GId: 1, CIds: [1,2]}]}, {SId: 3, GIds: [{GId: 1, CIds: [1]}]}]
    },
    {
      "BId": 2,
      "Name": "Test2",
      "States": [{SId: 2, GIds: [{GId: 1, CIds: [1]}, {GId: 2, CIds: [2]}]}, {SId: 3, GIds: [{GId: 1, CIds: [3,4]}]}]
    }
]
```

```js
const array1 = [
        {"BId": 1,
          "Name": "Test1",
        },
        {
          "BId": 2,
          "Name": "Test2",
        }
    ];
    
const array2 = [
        {
          "Id": 1,
          "BId": 1,
          "SId": 2,
          "GId": 1,
          "CId": 1
        },
        {
          "Id": 2,
          "BId": 1,
          "SId": 2,
          "GId": 1,
          "CId": 2          
        },
        {
          "Id": 3,
          "BId": 1,
          "SId": 3,
    "GId": 1,
          "CId": 1
        },
  {
          "Id": 1,
          "BId": 2,
          "SId": 2,
    "GId": 1,
          "CId": 1
        },
        {
          "Id": 2,
          "BId": 2,
          "SId": 2,
    "GId": 2,
          "CId": 2
        },
        {
          "Id": 3,
          "BId": 2,
          "SId": 3,
    "GId": 1,
          "CId": 3
        },
        {
          "Id": 3,
          "BId": 2,
          "SId": 3,
    "GId": 1,
          "CId": 4
        },
    ];

    const result =  [
        {
          "BId": 1,
          "Name": "Test1",
          "States": [{SId: 2, GIds: [{GId: 1, CIds: [1,2]}]}, {SId: 3, GIds: [{GId: 1, CIds: [1]}]}]
        },
        {
          "BId": 2,
          "Name": "Test2",
          "States": [{SId: 2, GIds: [{GId: 1, CIds: [1]}, {GId: 2, CIds: [2]}]}, {SId: 3, GIds: [{GId: 1, CIds: [3,4]}]}]
        }
    ]   
            
const all = array1.map(arr => {
    let States = []
    array2
    .filter(e => arr.BId === e.BId)
    .map(e => {
        const {SId, GId, CId} = e
        States.push({SId, GId, CId})
    });

    const States2 = States.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        let CIds = []
        const {SId, GId, CId} = cur
        const idx = acc.findIndex(e => e.SId === SId)
        
        if (idx !== -1) {            
            acc[idx].GIds.filter(g => g.GId === GId)
            .map(g => {
                if(acc[idx].GIds.findIndex(g => g.GId === GId && g.CIds.findIndex(c => CId)) === -1 )
                {
                    acc[idx].GIds.push({GId, CIds: [...CIds, CId]});
                };
            });
            
        } else {
            acc.push({SId, GIds: [{GId, CIds: [CId]}]});
        }

        return acc
    },[]);

    return {...arr, States2};
 });
 
console.dir(all);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const array1 = [{
  "BId": 1,
  "Name": "Test1",
 },
 {
  "BId": 2,
  "Name": "Test2",
 }
];

const array2 = [{
  "Id": 1,
  "BId": 1,
  "SId": 2,
  "GId": 1,
  "CId": 1
 },
 {
  "Id": 2,
  "BId": 1,
  "SId": 2,
  "GId": 1,
  "CId": 2
 },
 {
  "Id": 3,
  "BId": 1,
  "SId": 3,
  "GId": 1,
  "CId": 1
 },
 {
  "Id": 1,
  "BId": 2,
  "SId": 2,
  "GId": 1,
  "CId": 1
 },
 {
  "Id": 2,
  "BId": 2,
  "SId": 2,
  "GId": 2,
  "CId": 2
 },
 {
  "Id": 3,
  "BId": 2,
  "SId": 3,
  "GId": 1,
  "CId": 3
 },
 {
  "Id": 3,
  "BId": 2,
  "SId": 3,
  "GId": 1,
  "CId": 4
 },
];

const result = [{
  "BId": 1,
  "Name": "Test1",
  "States": [{
   SId: 2,
   GIds: [{
    GId: 1,
    CIds: [1, 2]
   }]
  }, {
   SId: 3,
   GIds: [{
    GId: 1,
    CIds: [1]
   }]
  }]
 },
 {
  "BId": 2,
  "Name": "Test2",
  "States": [{
   SId: 2,
   GIds: [{
    GId: 1,
    CIds: [1]
   }, {
    GId: 2,
    CIds: [2]
   }]
  }, {
   SId: 3,
   GIds: [{
    GId: 1,
    CIds: [3, 4]
   }]
  }]
 }
]

const all = array1.map(arr => {
 let States = []
 const objj = {};
 array2
  .filter(e => arr.BId === e.BId)
  .map(e => {
   const {
    SId,
    GId,
    CId
   } = e
   States.push({
    SId,
    GId,
    CId
   })
  });



 States.forEach(valu => {
  const {
   SId,
   GId,
   CId
  } = valu;

  if (objj[SId]) {
   if (objj[SId]["GIds"][GId]) {
    objj[SId]["GIds"][GId]["CIds"].push(CId);
   } else {
    objj[SId]["GIds"][GId] = {
     GId: GId,
     CIds: [CId]
    };
   }
  } else {
   objj[valu.SId] = {
    SId: SId,
    GIds: {
     [GId]: {
      GId: GId,
      CIds: [CId]
     }
    }
   };
  }
 })
 let resu = Object.values(objj).map(val => {
  const {
   SId,
   GIds
  } = val
  return {
   SId: SId,
   GIds: Object.values(GIds)
  }
 })




 return {
  ...arr,
  States: resu
 };
});

console.log(all);
```

Comment: Try this one just modified ur reducing function

Comment: not sure I understand exactly what is happening with objj but this is obviously working. If you don't mind can you elaborate on what the purpose of objj is and how you're allowed to use it like that!

Comment: objj will be a json having unique sid and gid values as key
{
  "2": {
    "SId": 2,
    "GIds": {
      "1": {
        "GId": 1,
        "CIds": [
          1,
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "3": {
    "SId": 3,
    "GIds": {
      "1": {
        "GId": 1,
        "CIds": [
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
Basic idea behind this is storing sid value and gid value as keys of the json object.
Since the result array is made up of unique sid and gid.values stored in objj can be used to get the end result